How to Track User Progress in SCORM Content Embedded via an iFrame from AWS S3?
I have embedded a SCORM package hosted in an AWS S3 bucket into my website using an iFrame. The SCORM content displays correctly, but I would like to track the user's progress—specifically which slides the user has completed and how far they've progressed through the content.
<iframe id="scormPlayer" src="https://scorm-package.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/scorm/hurak-learning/fire-marshal-fire-warden-online/Introduction/index.html" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe>

How can I track which slides the user has completed and their overall progress within the SCORM content? I'm using SCORM 2004 and would prefer to manage the data within my own system without relying on third-party services.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

It is not sufficient to just load the HTML file from the package into an iframe, the content itself will expect to interact with the SCORM RTE provided by a SCORM player. What "progress" is then captured is largely up to the content itself and what data it provides to the SCORM player via the SCORM RTE API. Learn more about the SCORM RTE here: https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/ see https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/ for an Overview.
After reviewing that information, if you are interested in integrating rather than building a SCORM player I'd suggest looking at https://rusticisoftware.com/solutions/lmss/#delivery (disclosure: I work for Rustici Software).
(This is related to the question here: The Content was unable to locate the SCORM API Adapter)

Hello Brian I hope you are well. That means I need to build scorm player first ?

An open source RTE you can try is https://github.com/jcputney/scorm-again
